# FFmpeg error when doing first pass of WebM encoding: Unrecognized option 'auto-alt-ref'

Tags: macos, command-line, ffmpeg, webm

I'm using OS X Mavericks (10.9.4) and installed ffmpeg from homebrew.

When executing this command (assuming input file exists):

`ffmpeg -i ololo.wmv -vf scale=500:-1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 20 -pass 1 ololo.webm`

I get this output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 18 2014 22:48:21 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Unrecognized option 'auto-alt-ref'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Why? According to [this page on webmproject.org](http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg), this option should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default ffmpeg does not include libvpx.
after executing `brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvpx` the problem is gone. This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13629348/1418097

Comment: For the future try to always specify the encoder you want rather than having ffmpeg auto-select one. Then you would've gotten "unknown encoder libvpx".

Comment: @slhck of course, now I understand. I just used a template from an online guide for creating `WebM`s and (obviously) were knowing almost nothing about ffmpeg. But it turned out, one needs to understand what's going on, otherwise it won't work. :D

Comment: Ah, I see. It's not your fault, of course. I'd rather say the online guide needs a bit of an update then — do you have a link? You don't necessarily have to understand everything as long as the description is also aimed at people with less experience.

Comment: @slhck it's in russian language... and not really a complete guide. just some examples for people who can guess everything from them. Maybe I will write another guide at some day.

Comment: There's also http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8 (shameless plug, I wrote it :P)

Comment: @slhck I used ffmpeg with my script, which does 2-pass encoding trying to fit in a given file size: https://github.com/magicgoose/webm-buddy/blob/master/convert-to-webm.py